# Magento2 message manager doesn't work

Tags: adminhtml, magento2, magento2-dev-beta, messages

I'm trying to use the message manager in magento2 (admin side) by object injection but when i add it to my controller - my controller doesn't run.

```
class Example
{
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function method( ) {
        ..
        $message = '...';
        $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: clear the contents of var/generation.

Comment: Cool! it almost works...
Now it shows the error message only when I refresh the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface - \Magento\Framework\Message\Manager uses sessons. Try to clean browser cookies

Comment: I tried opening it in incognito but still i need to refresh the page in order to see the message.

Comment: Try to clean cookies and brwoser cache, not incognito mode. Try also clean up /var directory